# Datetime subtract, datespan divide

Tags: c#-4.0

I have to subtract two dates and divide it by the number of cells

```
Suppose: 
DateTime d1 = 10/6/2010 12:00:00 AM
DateTime d2  = 10/9/2010 11:59:59 PM
#Cells = 5
```

Now how do I find the delta? Is the delta a TimeSpan? `delta = (d2.subtract(d1))/5`? This does not work.

Pls suggest
Sun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeSpan delta = TimeSpan.FromTicks((d2.Subtract(d1).Ticks) / 5);
```

Comment: It should be noted that division by Ticks is division by Int64/long which will discard the decimal component.

Answer (score 1):

```
delta = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((d2 - d1).TotalSeconds / 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d2.Subtract(d1)
```

That results in a DateTime out which can not be divided by 5.

```
var ts = d1 - d2;
```

ts will have a Type of TimeSpan.

You can then get your delta using this TimeSpan since you haven't specified what Type delta is you can have it be a double representing 1/5 of seconds or 1/5 of minutes or whatever.

```
var delta_sec = ts.TotalSeconds / 5.0;
var delta_min = ts.TotalMinutes / 5.0;
```